how to include :: in the text of an org mode list without it generating a description list?
I am trying to use org mode to make notes about my programs.  The formatting for some of the items in my lists were pushed to the left.  I realized that my code includes double colons :: and org is interpreting this as a command to generate a description list.  How can I include :: as plain text in an org mode list?  I tried surrounding the text with equal signs to make verbatim (some of the code has equal signs too), and tried using tildes to flag the text as code, but no dice.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16944298/org-mode-inline-code-with-equals-signs

AFAICT, a double-colon is interpreted as the separator in a description list if, and only if, it is prefixed and suffixed by white space: e.g.
- foo::bar is an item called "foo::bar"
- So is bar::baz

is an ordinary, bulleted list (try exporting to PDF e.g.). It is only when white space precedes and follows the double-colon that the description interpretation is in force:
- foo :: bar is a description item
- bar :: baz is another

White space on one side (before OR after) does not make it into a description list: you got to have it on both sides.
If you absolutely have to have white space around the double-colon, insert a zero-width space between it and one of the spaces. You can do that with C-x 8 RET zero width space RET.
Here is an example:
* List of things to do

** Bulleted list

Here is a list:

 - foo ::bar is a bulleted item

 - bar:: baz is another

 - baz::foo is a third


 
** Description list

Here is a description list:

 - foo :: bar is a description item

 - bar :: baz is another


 
** Bulleted list - despite appearances

Here is a bulleted list with zero-width spaces inserted before the double-colons,
thereby rendering them inoperative:

 - foo ​:: bar is not a description item

 - bar ​:: baz is another

